# Why can't I have a series of divisions in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compute the profit margin for each month of the year.

I have already calculated a revenue and revenue minus tax for every month. However, when I try to go further, I always have the same number for each of the 12 months. When I change the division sign to a multiplication, everything is ok.

```
##Profit margin for each month = profit after tax divided by revenue 
(after tax/revenue)

for i in range(0,12):
    result = revenue[i] - expenses[i]
    profit_tax = result - (result * 0.3)

    profit_margin = profit_tax / result

    print (profit_margin)
```

Comment: profit_margin = profit_tax / result = (result - (result *0.3)) / result = result * (1 - 0.3) / result = 0.7

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple math.

```
profit_margin = profit / result = (result - (result * 0.3)) / result
              = (result * 0.7) / result
              = 0.7
```

You are doing something wrong, so please check it.

This seems an off-topic for programming and so I flagged.